# is There ANY WAY To acess a NAS server over the internet without using any VPN or any ip router config

Tags: samba4, ubuntu-22.04

I'm trying to acess my samba server over the internet but I don't know how to do it without setting up a VPN or something which I don't want to do. I can't do anything with VPN's or router configs since my decos doesn't have any option for port forwarding and stuff like that.

Comment: This is very strange requirement: to access a local service remotely and without setting up VPN. Are you sure you are this is a business requirement?

Comment: @NikitaKipriyanov just for a 84tb NAS which I need to access overseas.

Comment: How does this circumstance change my concern that the lack of proper networking capability on site is a strange business requirement?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [ZeroTier](https://www.zerotier.com) to create a layer-2 P2P VPN between your workstation and Samba server.

This should not require any firewall changes.

Comment: Would I just make a vpn on there and connect both of my systems to it?

Comment: it didn't work.

Comment: You should provide more information if you need assistance.

Answer (score 0):

You absolutely need to have a way to listen to some port on some public address to accept connections. But this "acceptance point" can be outside and not associated with your unconfigurable firewall.

For instance, you can rent a VPS with the public static IP address, configure a tunnel with it, and forward port on that VPS, or use it as the VPN endpoint for remote connections. The ZeroTier solution suggested in other answer is a kind of this (it is like "somebody already built this remote VPS"). The downside is that it makes you rely on third party.

---

Having said that, I should mention, in a business environment you can rather demand your requirements to be satisfied and you'll be given the power to set up firewall, forward ports and so on. It is not quite normal situation for the business to not to be able to have a VPN.